# Does linux mint use the ubuntu repos or their own repos?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, repository

I prefer the cinnamon desktop included with Linux Mint but there are some applications that I require that are in the ubuntu repos.

**Does linux mint use the ubuntu repos or their own repos?**

I know you can install Cinnamon on top of Ubuntu (that's what I have right now) but [doing so requires using third-party community repos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop?lq=1).

Comment: I saw some info in wikipedia saying that Linux Mint did in the past use the Ubuntu repos. But I'm not about today's Linux Mint 17 and onward.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124135/difference-between-ubuntu-and-linux-mint

Comment: That's a year old; the question was about current release, which seems to be http://packages.linuxmint.com/ not directly tied to Ubuntu.  But many packages could have been rebuilt from Ubuntu.  Likewise, almost all of the packages in Ubuntu are rebuilt from Debian.

Comment: i went to packages.linuxmint.com and click on Mint 17... the list doesn't even have gcc, g++, glibc, boost, etc... so where do they get those from?

Comment: See what's listed in the `/etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}` in a live Mint environment (cd/usb boot)?

Comment: @Darael Ya. Downloading now. (Probably won't be first answer tho...)

Comment: @ThomasDickey and Mint have since decided to be based on the current Ubuntu LTS release (aside from LMDE, of course). Releases since 14.04 came out are all based on 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

That does not prevent you from using ubuntu packages, either manually or with judicious uses from repos. I have been using some Ubuntu packages in Debian with varying degrees of success. At worst you can test install them manually.